# Problemas con el DNSMasq en Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, dns, puertos

estoy creando un **servidor web** en **Ubuntu**, instalé el **DNSmasq** y estoy teniendo problemas con el **puerto 53**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro encontrar solución, ¿me podéis echar una mano?

***P.D.:*** En la configuración de Virtual Box, en el apartado redes, estoy usando la opción Adaptador Puente (por si tiene algo que ver)

Comment: Para poder ver el campo `PID/Program name` deberás teclear `sudo netstat -tupln`. ¿Es posible que tengas instalado otro servidor DNS en tu equipo? Si marcaste la opción de servidor DNS durante la instalación de Ubuntu te habrá instalado `bind9`. Confírmame el resultado de ese `netstat` y con ello podré ayudarte a dejar el equipo correctamente configurado.

Answer (score 0):

Mira debes deshabilitar el proceso `systemd-resolv` que puedes ver al ejecutar el comando (verifica cual proceso está escuchando el puerto 53):

`sudo netstat -tupln | grep -w LISTEN`

Para deshabilitar ese servicio debes editar el archivo de configuración `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` allí debes agregar o editar la bandera `DNSStubListener=no` reinicias y ya puedes ejecutar tu servicio `dnsmasq` sin problema.